# Bash: Differences seen while executing command directly and while executing same command stored in string

Tags: bash, curl

**Ask**:

I am trying to understand the difference between executing a command directly and by storing the same in a string while using Bash.

**Details**:

I am trying to execute a CURL POST command. Since I am constructing the command by getting inputs from the user, I want to log the exact command I am executing. For this, I constructed the command in a string and tried to execute it. However, I see that it is not working in the same way in both the cases (I have substituted real values with fake values to ensure that I don't expose confidential information):

```
curl_command_1="curl --write-out "%{response_code}" --silent -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "${http_command}/resource" -d '{ "argument1": "'"${argument1}"'", "argument2": "'"${argument2}"'", "argument3": "'"${argument3}"'" }'"
echo $curl_command_1
ret_val_1=eval $curl_command_1
echo $ret_val_1
ret_val_2=`$curl_command_1`
echo $ret_val_2
ret_val_3=`curl --write-out "%{response_code}" --silent -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "${http_command}/resource" -d '{ "argument1": "'"${argument1}"'", "argument2": "'"${argument2}"'", "argument3": "'"${argument3}"'" }'`
echo $ret_val_3

curl_command_2="curl --write-out "%{response_code}" --silent -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "${http_command}/resource" -d '{ "argument1": \"${argument1}\", "argument2": \"${argument2}\", "argument3": \"${argument3}\" }'"
echo $curl_command_2
ret_val_1=eval $curl_command_2
echo $ret_val_1
ret_val_2=`$curl_command_2`
echo $ret_val_2
ret_val_3=`curl --write-out "%{response_code}" --silent -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "${http_command}/resource" -d '{ "argument1": \"${argument1}\", "argument2": \"${argument2}\", "argument3": \"${argument3}\" }'`
echo $ret_val_3
```

**Observations:**

1. The third case works fine in both success and failure cases.
2. In the first two cases, I get a large string of numbers as output in both success and failure cases. Not sure why.

**Confirmation on values used:**

1. Since this is a `POST` command, I did not execute all three with the same values in one execution. I used allowed values for the three arguments in each case.

Comment: Don't use parameters to store executable code; define a function that takes the user input as arguments.

Comment: Use a tool like `jq` to construct the JSON, instead of relying on parameter expansions to produce valid JSON.